# simplify boolean function

Tags: boolean-algebra, function

I have tried to simplify a boolean function. Unfortunately it is wrong.

**Question**: Where is my mistake?

\$ f = x_4x_2 + \overline {(x_3 + x_2)x_2 \cdot 1} + x_2 x_0\$

\$ f= x_4 x_2 + \overline {(x_3 + x_2) x_2} + x_2 x_0\$

\$ f = x_4 x_2 + ( \overline{x_3} \overline{x_2}) + \overline {x_2} + x_2 x_0\$

\$ f = \overline { \overline {x_4 x_2 + (\overline {x_3} \overline{x_2}) + \overline {x_2}+ x_2 x_0}} \$

\$ f = \overline { \overline{x_4} + \overline{x_2} (x_3 + x_2) x_2 \overline{x_2} + x_0}\$

\$ f = \overline{ \overline{x_4}+ \overline{x_0}} \$

\$ f = x_4x_0\$

The correct solution would be:

\$ f = \overline {x_2} + x_0 + x_4\$

Comment: in step 3 it should be x3x2 not x3+x2

Comment: The negation over x3x2 at line 3 is splitted in Android EESE application, but a single line in Samsung's default web browser.  The real error is how your double negation is expanded after line 4. That double negation is totally unnecessary action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in line 3. It should be like this:

$$\overline{(x_3+x_2)x_2} = \overline{(x_3+x_2)} + \overline{x_2} = \overline{x_3} \cdot \overline{x_2} + \overline{x_2} = \overline{x_2} (\overline{x_3} + 1) = \overline{x_2}$$

This gives you:

$$x_4x_2 + \overline{x_2} + x_2x_0 = x_2(x_4+x_0)+\overline{x_2}$$

To simplify this, we can write:

$$\overline{\overline{x_2(x_4+x_0)+\overline{x_2}}} = \overline{(\overline{x_2}+\overline{(x_4+x_0)}) \cdot x_2} = \overline{\overline{x_2}\cdot x_2 + \overline{(x_4+x_0)} \cdot x_2} =$$
$$= \overline{0+\overline{(x_4+x_0)} \cdot x_2} = (x_4 + x_0) + \overline{x_2}$$

which is equal to \$x_4 + x_0 + \overline{x_2}\$.

You can always write a simple C program to see where did you go wrong.

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {

    uint8_t byte;

    /* A number of all possible combinations.
    For 5 variables it would be 0b11111 etc. */
    uint8_t MAX = 0b1111;

    /* Print header */
    printf("x4 x3 x2 x0 | f1 f2 f3  f\n");

    for (byte=0; byte<=MAX; byte++)
    {
        /* Get individual bits (combinations) */
        uint8_t x0 = (byte & (1<<0)) >> 0; /* my x0 is your x0 */
        uint8_t x1 = (byte & (1<<1)) >> 1; /* my x1 is your x2 */
        uint8_t x2 = (byte & (1<<2)) >> 2; /* my x2 is your x3 */
        uint8_t x3 = (byte & (1<<3)) >> 3; /* my x3 is your x4 */

        /* Logic functions */
        uint8_t f1 = (x3 && x1) || !((x2 || x1) && x1 && 0b1) || (x1 && x0);
        uint8_t f2 = (x3 && x1) || !((x2 || x1) && x1) || (x1 && x0);
        uint8_t f3 = (x3 && x1) || !(x2 && x1) || (!x1) || (x1 && x0);

        /* Final solution */
        uint8_t f = (!x1) || x0 || x3;

        /* Print truth table */
        printf(" %d  %d  %d  %d |  %d  %d  %d  %d", x3, x2, x1, x0, f1, f2, f3, f);

        /* Print wrong line indicator */
        if ((f2!=f1) || (f3!=f1) || (f!=f1))
            printf(" <");

        printf("\n");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is \$ \overline{x_3} \cdot \overline{x_2} + \overline{x_2} = \overline{x_2}\$?

Comment: Because \$ \overline{x_3} \cdot \overline{x_2} + \overline{x_2} = \overline{x_2} (\overline{x_3}+1) \$, and \$ \overline{x_3} + 1 \$ is always true.

Comment: One last question:  \$ x_2(x_4+x_0)+\overline{x_2} \$ Why is \$ x_2 \$ removed ? I thought that \$ x_2 + \overline {x_2} = 1\$ and both \$ x_2\$ negated and not negated should disappear

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include a more detailed explanation. I hope this helps!